# Create a 44-byte header with ffmpeg

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, wav

I made a program using ffmpeg libraries that converts an audio file to a wav file. Except the only problem is that it doesn't create a 44-byte header. When input the file into Kaldi Speech Recognition, it produces the error:

`ERROR (online2-wav-nnet2-latgen-faster:Read4ByteTag():wave-reader.cc:74) WaveData: expected 4-byte chunk-name, got read errror`

I ran the file thru shntool and it reports a 78-byte header. Is there anyway I can get the standard 44-byte header using ffmpeg libraries?

Comment: can you use hexdup or a related tool to show the current header contents? I'm guessing it has metadata or extended wave descriptions (using hex instead of 2-byte audio identifiers), but it's hard to know for sure (ext hex should be off by default, and metadata is pretty typical so I don't know why your software would complain about that).

Comment: I see I will take a look. I was thinking that I would just make my own header and let ffmpeg still do the transcoding. Should I use fwrite or some other function to create the header?

Comment: Yea it looks like there is some metadata that use inserted by ffmpeg that caused the header to be larger than 44-bytes. If there way only a way to prevent that.

Comment: Can you hexdump the header and put it in your post? It's easier to give suggestions on how to get rid of it if I can see what type of metadata it inserted (there's more than one possibility...).

Comment: Actually, I got rid of it just a little bit ago. FFmpeg inserted some metadata about the encoder, so I use av_dict_set and then then passed it into the avformat_write_header and it is now 44-bytes.  But here is the hexdump from before: 
52 49 46 46 06 90 00 00  57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20  |RIFF....WAVEfmt |
10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00  40 1f 00 00 80 3e 00 00  |........@....>..|
02 00 10 00 4c 49 53 54  1a 00 00 00 49 4e 46 4f  |....LIST....INFO|
49 53 46 54 0e 00 00 00  4c 61 76 66 35 36 2e 33  |ISFT....Lavf56.3|
36 2e 31 30 30 00 64 61  74 61 c0 8f 00 00 00 00  |6.100.data......|

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg inserts some metadata about the encoder into the header file. Here is the hexdump of the header before the fix:

`00000000  52 49 46 46 06 90 00 00  57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20  |RIFF....WAVEfmt |
00000010  10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00  40 1f 00 00 80 3e 00 00  |........@....>..|
00000020  02 00 10 00 4c 49 53 54  1a 00 00 00 49 4e 46 4f  |....LIST....INFO|
00000030  49 53 46 54 0e 00 00 00  4c 61 76 66 35 36 2e 33  |ISFT....Lavf56.3|
00000040  36 2e 31 30 30 00 64 61  74 61 c0 8f 00 00 00 00  |6.100.data......|`

as you can see Lavf56.36.100 is the encoder in the header. Here is the portion of code that I used to get rid of it.

```
std::cout<<"------------------BEFORE-----------------------"<<std::endl;
std::cout<< av_dict_count ( (*ofmt_ctx)->metadata) <<std::endl;
std::cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<std::endl; 
if(av_dict_set(&(*ofmt_ctx)->metadata,"ISFT",NULL, AV_DICT_IGNORE_SUFFIX)){
 std::cerr<<"Nope it, didn't work :("<<std::endl;
}

ret = avformat_write_header(*ofmt_ctx,&(*ofmt_ctx)->metadata );
if (ret < 0) {
  std::cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
  av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Error occurred when writing header to file\n");
  return ret;
}
std::cout<<"------------------AFTER-----------------------"<<std::endl;
std::cout<< av_dict_count ( (*ofmt_ctx)->metadata) <<std::endl;
std::cout<<"-------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
```

Here is the hexdump afterwards:

`00000000  52 49 46 46 e4 8f 00 00  57 41 56 45 66 6d 74 20  |RIFF....WAVEfmt |
00000010  10 00 00 00 01 00 01 00  40 1f 00 00 80 3e 00 00  |........@....>..|
00000020  02 00 10 00 64 61 74 61  c0 8f 00 00 00 00 00 00  |....data........|
00000030  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ff ff 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|`

shntool now report 44-bytes

(NOTE:ofmt_ctx was a ** in this function that I made, hence why referencing the metadata dictionary as `&(*ofmt_ctx)->metadata`)